How to use the VS Code "outline" feature for markdown variant
I sometimes use a variant of markdown (called Madoko) to write with. Although there is syntax highlighting support for it in VS Code, I can't seem to get the "Outline" feature to work with this file type. If I set the file type to "markdown", I get the outline, but then the proper syntax highlighting is lost.
I tried adding this to my settings.json as suggested here but it didn't seem to have any effect:
    "[madoko]": {
        "outline.showStrings": true,
}

I assumed that would make the "outline" "show strings"  for the file type "madoko" but I guess not.
It could be that this feature is not supported, as this post seems to suggest, but it seems like it should be fairly simple to implement or find a workaround.
I tried using several Extensions such as OutlinePlus but didn't have any success with that.
Thanks in advance.
